# Tables disappeared from phpMyAdmin but visible via command line

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp, timemachine

I'm using MAMP and OS X 10.10.1 and use Time Machine to backup my local environment. I've recently had several occurances where a database disappears from phpMyAdmin and is inaccessible to my local site but is visible if I connect through mysql on the command line. I do however see that some of the databases are conflicted and are listed like so:

```
wp_commentmeta     
#mysql50#wp_comments (MacBook Pro de...conflicted
wp_comments
```

What is the best way to get rid of these conflicted files? I think the conflicted file contains the most recent information so I would prefer to keep that if possible.

I'm guessing this is the reason for the tables disappearing from phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that keeps the databases from appearing indeed seems to be the message itself. Removing the `#mysql50#` and the conflict message as well as the less recent version of the table will leave the database in its most recent state before the conflict occurred.